# Spurious period on badge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Any of the badge pages show a small dot above the badge image:

[image]

While it may not be that obvious, it is more apparent on other sites (here's a take from [Meta.TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com)):

[image]

Comment: -1 not enough eeeek!

Comment: @Cody You're not satisfied enough with the freehand red arrows? :P

Comment: Eeeeekkkkkkk, now I cannot unsee the very small but very distracting period!

Comment: `+1` This spurious period confuses and infuriates me! `:)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Gone.

Someone must have fixed it!

Probably I did, since I probably introduced it, too...

Or maybe you imagined it...

Yes, it must be so.

It's a figment of your imagination!

*waves hand and disappears in a puff of smoke*

Comment: Nice bug cleanup so far, you're really on a roll! :)